# User Agent No IIS

Tags: iis

Existe uma forma de setar um User Agent de uma Smart TV no IIS? 
Estou precisando fazer isso, para testar um aplicativo que fizemos para uma Smart TV da LGE, mas os nossos videos só funcionam com o User Agent das Smarts.

Comment: Defina setar um *user agent*.

Comment: O IIS não é um *browser*, então não é possível. Tente mostrar melhor o que você deseja.

Comment: Tem um sistema de segurança que valida o user agent da chamada, quando eu uso um app de navegador para forçar o user agent como o User-Agent-Switcher, quando eu coloco a url que eu quero tocar no navegador direto com esse setado com o user agent da LGE BROWSER funciona, mas quando eu chamo de um app em um app publicado como no IIS, não funciona porque ele valida um valor que retorna do Server, não dando para forçar que nem quando eu coloco direto no navegador. Eu vi esse link  
goo.gl/I7mDCS para ter um norte

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender. A sua app .net é que faz a requisição?

Comment: Eu tenho um app WEB em .net que recebe uma URL de um vídeo de um servidor, essa URL é codificada para tocar somente em Devices: TVs Smart e Mobile, ela bate em um load balance que verifica o User Agent da requisição e devolve uma outra URL. Eu usei um plugin de navegagor, mas só consigo tocar o video quando coloco a URL direto, quando esta em um Servidor com IIS ou Apache elas são bloqueadas, dai estou tentando ver se consigo setar neles um User Agent, vi uns links como coloquei acima, mas não consegui colocar um de uma Smart.